# php array filter function issue with variable

Tags: php

I have a problem using a variable inside this [array filter](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php):

```
$lteam_id = 25;
$flt_lteam = array_filter($events, function($obj)

{
return $obj['team_id'] == $lteam_id && $obj['type'] == 'kick' && $obj['minute'] <= 75 ;
});
```

As soon as I replace `$lteam_id`with `25` it works and I get a result. Using the variable results in an `array(0) { }`... Hope you can help me here on using the variables correctly.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) function, so you can use `use` statement to pass variable to it:

```
$lteam_id = 25;
$flt_lteam = array_filter($events, function($obj) use ($lteam_id)
{
    return $obj['team_id'] == $lteam_id && $obj['type'] == 'kick' && $obj['minute'] <= 75 ;
});
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! Works!

Answer (score 0):

$lteam_id is not accessible in closure inside array_filter(). either pass the variable as argument of the closure or use `using`

```
$flt_lteam = array_filter($events, function($obj) using($lteam_id)

{
return $obj['team_id'] == $lteam_id && $obj['type'] == 'kick' && $obj['minute'] <= 75 ;
});
```